# KeyError while using str[:] in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a table with row IDs:

| ID | fruit | place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 61725RN | apple | London |
| 12381YH | banana | Toronto |

I need to make a list with only a number part of IDs : ['61725', '12381']

I write the code below and receive a "KeyError". However, the column name is bold in my code, so it is an index.

```
nums = df['ID'].str[:5]
```

Comment: try `df.reset_index()` after that try `df['ID'].str[:5]`

Comment: Please provide the full error but I am guessing there is a leading or trailing space in the column name: `'ID '` check `df.columns` to see

Answer (score -1):

You must transform the target to string *before* slicing, EDIT : and you'll have to make a loop :

```py
    nums=[]
    for i in range(len(df)):
        nums.append(str(df['ID'][i])[:5])
```

sorry i didn't check the dataframe problem. Works now.